# ESP32 BLE Bluetooth Serial to Hardware Serial Bridge

Tags: serial, bluetooth, esp32, bluetooth-low-energy, iphone

I'm looking for a way to use serial devices with my iOS iPhone without buying a $20 device.

I have an ESP32 which can do Bluetooth Serial to Serial using [this code](https://github.com/avinabmalla/ESP32_BleSerial/blob/master/examples/BleSerial_Bridge/BleSerial_Bridge.ino) but if I replace the Serial with `Serial2.begin(38400, SERIAL_8N1, 16, 17);` it doesn't work and no longer sends messages from Serial2 to SerialBT.

Are there any working implementations of a pure bridge between SerialBT and HardwareSerial? I just want the raw bytes sent from one to the other and vice versa.

Comment: In the first place I would write a local echo code for Serial2 only without the BT stack, to verify this part of the needed functions.

Comment: add the sketch to the question. the one which is not working